# Show constraints from different schema Oracle

Tags: oracle, schema, constraints

I know for user_constraints and all constraint and i tried something like

```
select * from user_constraints
```

but i want to see constraints from different schema?

EDIT: I want to show constraints from certain schema, not all of them

Comment: So use all_constraints.

Comment: Your question seems to suggest you already know about `all_constraints`, and [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5249.htm) covers both (and `dba_constraints`), so... what is the question?

Comment: The thing is I need constraints from certain schema, not from all. I tried something like SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE USER = 'schemaName' but i didn't get any result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `all_constraints` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1046.htm) does not have a `USER` column. [`USER` refers to you](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions227.htm#sthref1750), the account performing the query. You can see that with something like `select user from dual`. Your query will either return all rows, if `schemaName` is also you, or no rows - nothing in between.

You need to filter on the `OWNER` column:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE OWNER = 'schemaName'
```

... remembering that the schema name is usually case-insentitive and needs to be supplied in upper-case, e.g. `WHERE OWNER = 'MYSCHEMA'.

You may also need to filter on `R_OWNER` or even `INDEX_OWNER` in some circumstances, it depends what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks man, i also tried owner, but i thought it wasn't case sensitive, and it didn't worked. now with upper case it works fine